# Why 0 is being ignored in slicing in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I typed this code for solving [this HackerEarth question](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/implementation/basics-of-implementation/practice-problems/algorithm/digit-problem/):

```
x, k = input().split()
str(x)
m=len(x)
d=9
print(int(str(d)*int(k)), end="") 
print(int(x[int(k):int(m)]))
```

It was partially accepted and many times it gave the wrong answer while checking all the outputs I found out that the code was consistently ignoring 0. For example:

When inputted this: `70843010538381368 7` the output was: `9999999538381368` but it should be: `99999990538381368`.

I don't know why 0 was being ignored and how to solve it.

Comment: You clearly did not understand casting. input will return a string and so does split. So no need for `str(x)`.

Later you are casting *m* to an integer although it already is an integer given by the number of chars in x.

Answer (score 1):

When you cast the second half to int, it doesn't print leading zeroes.  Just leave it a string:

```
x,k = input().split()
k = int(k)
print('9' * k + x[k:])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is the that you are casting a little bit too much.

Let us breakdown this statement: `print(int(x[int(k):int(m)]))`

`x` is a **string** of value *"70843010538381368"*

`k` is a **string** of value *"7"*

`m` is a **integer** of value *17*

---

First let's see what `x[int(k):int(m)]` will give us:

`k` and `m` are cast to **integers** such that `int(k)` is *7* and `int(m)` is *17*. Side note here, `m` was already an integer so casting it to integer is not needed.
`x[int(k):int(m)]` slices the **string** `x` from index 7 to 17.

`x[int(k):int(m)]  == '0538381368'`

---

#### The mistake

Once done you are casting the value to **integer**. And that is where it breaks.

`int(x[int(k):int(m)])` or if you will `int('0538381368')` is equal to *538381368*. **You are loosing the initial zero!**

---

Finally you are printing it, which implicitly casts to string: `str(538381368) == '538381368'`